# How to insert to database from combo box?

Tags: java, swing, crud, jcombobox

I'm just trying to make some combo box with value from database and I can choose it and insert it to database, but I had some error message. How to resolve that?

**Here my code:**

```
private void btnInputDataProdukActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String sql = "insert into tb_produk (produk_kat_id,produk_nm,produk_gndre,produk_size,produk_hrg) values (?,?,?,?,?)";
    try {
        PreparedStatement stat = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        stat.setString(1, txtNamaProduk.toString());
        String valueKat = cbKatProduk.getSelectedItem().toString();
        stat.setString(2, valueKat);
        String valueGender = cbGender.getSelectedItem().toString();
        stat.setString(3, valueGender);
        stat.setString(4, txtUkuran.toString());
        stat.setString(5, txtHarga.toString());
        stat.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Berhasil Disimpan");
        kosong();
        dataTable();
        lebarKolom();
        txtNamaProduk.requestFocus();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Gagal Disimpan" + e);
    }
}
```

**The combo box with value from DB**

```
public void tampil_combo(){
    String sql = "select kat_id from tb_kategori";
    try {
        java.sql.Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet res = stat.executeQuery(sql);
        while (res.next()) {
            Object[] ob = new Object[3];
            ob[0]=res.getString(1);
            
            cbKatProduk.addItem((String) ob[0]);
        }
        res.close();stat.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

[image: the error message]
[image: DB Tabel tb_produk]
[image: DB Tabel tb_kategori]

Comment: `catch (Exception e) { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog..` should better be `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); JOptionPane.showMessageDialog..` then copy/paste the *text* that appears in the console of the IDE. Speaking of text, post text rather than images of text. Speaking of IDEs, don't tag them unless the code works in a different IDE.

Answer (score 2):

`produkt_kat_id` is defined as an int in your database. But with

```
stat.setString(1, txtNamaProduk.toString());
```

you are setting a string. Also note that you are calling `toString()` on the combo box and not the selected value.

So you need to convert the selected value into an integer:

```
stat.setString(1, Integer.parseInt(txtNamaProduk.getSelectedItem()));
```

You would still need to add some error handling in case `txtNamaProduk.getSelectedItem()` returns null or in case the combo box can also contain other values than integers.

You will also need to change your code for the other fields that are defined as integers in the database.